# match two columns from one file to three columns from another file, print out lines from the file with two columns

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have file A with two columns, it looks like this:

```
7000000185249100 162280
7000000185249048 235500
7000000185249052 755361
7000000185249068 427550
7000000185249070 269102
7000000185249081 291122
```

And I have file B with three columns, it looks like this:

```
7000000185249100 1622651 1623044
7000000185249048 235104 235805
7000000185249146 2500324 2502635
7000000185249100 1218818 1221734
7000000185249468 88587 89699
7000000185249239 299691 300277
7000000185249315 769635 769986
7000000185249374 1548986 1549747
```

So what I wanted to do is to print out lines from file A,

1. if the number in first column in file A matches the number in first column in file B, and
2. the number in the second column in file A is within the range of the numbers in the second and third columns in file B.

Expected output will be:

```
7000000185249048 235500
```

I tried with the following code, but failed.

```
awk -F '\t' 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2,$3]=$0;next}{if(b=a[$1, >=$2 && <= $3]){print b}}' file B file A
```

Comment: how is `162280` within range of `1622651 1623044` or `1218818 1221734`?

Comment: Thanks Sundeep for pointing it out, it was a typo... It should be 1622800.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `join` to find common *1st* fields, then use `bash` to compare
   values:

   ```
   join --nocheck-order -j 1 A B | 
   while read a b c d ; do 
       [[ ( b -le d && b -ge c ) || ( b -le c && b -ge d ) ]] && echo $a $b
   done
   ```

   The *OP* spec states "*the number in the second column in file A is
   within the range of the numbers in the second and third columns in
   file B*".  This range might not ordered, so the logic between `[[`
   and `]]` handles it either way.  Example:

   - If *A2=3*, *B2=2*, and *B3=4*, that's matched by `( b -le d 
     &&  b -ge c )`.
   - If *A2=3*, *B2=**4***, and *B3=**2***, that's matched by `( b -le c 
     &&  b -ge d )`.
2. Not so good *GNU* `sed` code to turn each line of file *B* into two
       piped [`numgrep`](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/) commands that search file *A* for ranges, then
       `e`*valuate* the commands.  Because the resulting list of commands might have redundant output, pipe that to [`awk` to perform
   an unsorted *uniq*](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-one-liners-explained-part-two/):

   ```
       sed -n \
       's#\(\w*\)\W*\(\w*\)\W*\(\w*\)#numgrep /\1/ A\|numgrep /\2..\3,\3..\2/#e
        /./p' B |
       awk '!a[$0]++'
   ```

Output of either method:

```
7000000185249048 235500
```

Comment: [@Sundeep's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419239/match-two-columns-from-one-file-to-three-columns-from-another-file-print-out-li/419249#comment753252_419239) implies the first line output is an error.  If so, my code is buggy, and it's bugs coincidentally match the *OP*'s wrong output.  Hmm...

Comment: Fixed code error, problem was that a `,` in `numgrep` is a logical *OR*.  The code needs a logical *AND*, which required a pipe.  The revised code can still fail if field #1 of file *B* is within range of fields #2 & #3, and field #2 of file *A* is not.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help @agc! I really appreciated it. Yes, as Sundeep pointed out, I made a mistake in the example files. The expected output will be 7000000185249048 235500 only in this example. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jing, Glad to hear it worked.  Please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hi @agc , could you explain a little bit more about what [[ b -le d && b -ge c ]] || [[ b -le c && b -ge d ]] does? I think the first part is to select values in column b that are lower than or equal to values in column d but greater than or equal to values in column c. What about the second part ? And what does || do? Thanks!

Comment: @Jing, `||` means [*logical OR*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction#Truth_table), it means that if *either* of the tests in between `[[ ... ]]` is true, the `echo` gets run.  You're correct about the first part.  See revised answer for more info.